# Mouse Over Crashes Loading Screen

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I have a `LoadingScreen` that runs on a separated `Thread`:

```
public partial class LoadingScreen : Window
{
    #region Variables

    private static Thread _thread;
    private static LoadingScreen _loading;
    private static bool _isIndeterminate;

    #endregion

    public LoadingScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region Methods

    public static void ShowSplash(bool isIndeterminate = false)
    {
        _isIndeterminate = isIndeterminate;

        _thread = new Thread(OpenSplash)
        {
            IsBackground = true,
            Name = "Loading"
        };
        _thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        _thread.Start();
    }

    private static void OpenSplash()
    {
        _loading = new LoadingScreen();
        _loading.ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = _isIndeterminate;
        _loading.ShowDialog();

        _loading.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(Dispatcher.Run));
    }

    public static void CloseSplash()
    {
        if (_loading == null || _thread == null)
            return;

        _loading.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { _loading.Close(); }));
        _loading.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        _loading = null;
    }

    public static void Update(int value, string description)
    {
        Update((double)value, description);
    }

    public static void Update(double value, string description)
    {
        if (_loading == null)
            return;

        _loading.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            var da = new DoubleAnimation(value, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Math.Abs(_loading.ProgressBar.Value - value) * 12)))
            {
                EasingFunction = new PowerEase { Power = 3 }
            };

            _loading.ProgressBar.BeginAnimation(RangeBase.ValueProperty, da);
            _loading.TextBlock.Text = description;
        });
    }

    public static void Status(bool isIndeterminate)
    {
        if (_loading == null)
            return;

        _loading.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
       {
           _loading.ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = isIndeterminate;
       });
    }

    #endregion

    private void SplashScreen_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DragMove();
    }

    private void RestoreButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _loading.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            if (_loading.MiddleRowDefinition.Height == new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star))
            {
                _loading.MiddleRowDefinition.Height = new GridLength(0);
                _loading.RestoreButton.Content = "R";
                _loading.Height = 69;
            }
            else
            {
                _loading.MiddleRowDefinition.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
                _loading.RestoreButton.Content = "A"; //I removed my vector to test.
                _loading.Height = 200;
            }
        });
    }

    private void MinimizeButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _loading.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            _loading.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        });
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MySoftware.Util.LoadingScreen"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Bem Vindo" Height="200" Width="400" Topmost="True"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"
    MouseLeftButtonDown="SplashScreen_OnMouseLeftButtonDown">

<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ShowStoryBoard">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:5">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <BackEase Amplitude="2" EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="HideStoryBoard">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:5">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <PowerEase Power="4" EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="MiddleRowDefinition"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="21"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="18"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.Background>
        <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.5,1.3" GradientOrigin="0.5,1.1">
            <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" ScaleY="0.75" ScaleX="0.8"/>
                    <SkewTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                    <RotateTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="TranslateTransform" X="-0.5"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>

            <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E1EE" Offset="0.1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF70A6C8" Offset="1"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="30">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="WindowButtonStyle">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                            <Border x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    Margin="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Viewbox MaxHeight="15" MaxWidth="15" Stretch="Uniform">
                                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                </Viewbox>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

                <!--Default Values-->
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,5,0"/>

                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#60FFFFFF" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#90FFFFFF" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".6"/>
                        <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <Button x:Name="MinimizeButton" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}"
                Content="--" Width="30" Margin="0" Height="30"
                Click="MinimizeButton_OnClick"
                ToolTip="Minimize" ToolTipService.Placement="Top"/>
        <Button x:Name="RestoreButton" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}"
                Content="R" Width="30" Margin="0" Height="30"
                Click="RestoreButton_OnClick"
                ToolTip="Restore" ToolTipService.Placement="Top"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Image Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="DownOnly"
           Margin="20"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" x:Name="TextBlock" Text="Loading..." HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF202020"
               FontSize="16"/>

    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="3" x:Name="ProgressBar" Margin="4" Height="10" Maximum="100"/>
</Grid>
```

The problem happens when I hover one of the two buttons that this `LoadingScreen` contains, I don't even click, just hover and less than a second later, `Dispatcher.Run()` throws me a `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

I tested with or without a custom `Style` and with(out) a content (I removed my vector to simplify the code for this question), no different results.

I can easily drag to move the `Window` but I can't hover the `Buttons`. That's strange. Did I miss something while working with another thread and running a `Dispatcher`?

### EDIT:

Using a `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()` did nothing.
Removing the `Dispatcher.Run()` killed the other part of my app (Nothing else was appearing, just a white screen).
Removing the `STA` makes the app crash (It needs to be STA).

### EDIT 2:

The entire code is available.
The app uses .net 4.0, I forgot to say that.

Comment: The hover is happening in the GUI thread, the button logic you have is in a different thread; resolve that and you will resolve the problem.

Comment: What is `Dispatcher.Run()`? Simply use `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`, the thread will not progress further until window is closed. If you trying to make thread-safe splash screen, then you fail badly.

Comment: What happens when you comment out `ApartmentState.STA` line? Does the same behavior happen?

Comment: @OmegaMan Drag is not the problem. It's the hover of the button that crashes the window.

Comment: @Sinatr `Dispatcher.Run()` makes the UI to actually change, without that line, the progress bar is static.

Comment: I'll try changing the `Show()` to `ShowDialog()` and later I'll try removing the `STA`.

Comment: Is the splashscreen object a window or usercontrol?

Comment: @BenSteele `Window`.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the SplashScreen object, i believe that is an already reserved name. Could be confusing as the splashscreen object is normally an image

Comment: @BenSteele I just did, no different result.

Comment: @NIcke I have copied your code and I still dont get the issue. I am now thinking it must be the way that the window is called. Are you able to email me the solution? I will gladly have a look for you

Comment: @BenSteele I'm recreating a test ambient, I'll share with you via OneDrive link as soon as I can. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it was due to the the ToolTip. That explains why you have to hove your mouse over it for a short time. Ill add that to my test and see what i can come up with.

EDIT: I believe the issue is due to the way your starting your thread. Are you calling the Splash Screen from your Main Window? If you are, you will need to change the order of your code:

```
  public static void ShowSplash(bool isIndeterminate = false)
    {
        _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(OpenSplash))
        {
            IsBackground = true,
            Name = "Loading"
        };

        _thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        _thread.Start();
    }

    private static void OpenSplash()
    {
        //Run on another thread.
        _splash = new Splash();
        _isIndeterminate = false;

       _splash.Show();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();

        //_splash.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(Dispatcher.Run));
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run(); //HERE!
        _splash.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { _splash.ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = _isIndeterminate; });

    }
```

In my original post, i was creating the window from the App.xaml.cs file, here no dispatcher was running at the time which is why it works. When it is being called from the window, it is being called from the Main Windows dispatcher thread, with the way you had setup the thread it was always calling off the main window. When i set it up like this I then get the same issue as you. By changing the thread creation it will work as you have intended.

See the change in the ShowSplash and OpenSplash methods for the details

**ORINGINAL POST**: I tried duplicating you code but i cant get it to fail. Please see my code below, does it work on your system?

App.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static Splash _splash;
    private static bool _isIndeterminate = false;
    private static Thread _thread;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowSplash(true);

        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    public static void ShowSplash(bool isIndeterminate = false)
    {
        _isIndeterminate = isIndeterminate;

        _thread = new Thread(OpenSplash)
        {
            IsBackground = true,
            Name = "Loading"
        };
        _thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        _thread.Start();
    }

    private static void OpenSplash()
    {
        //Run on another thread.
        _splash = new Splash();
        _splash.Show();

        _splash.ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = _isIndeterminate;
        //_splash.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(Dispatcher.Run));
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run(); //HERE!
    }

    public static void CloseSplash()
    {
        if (_splash == null || _thread == null)
            return;

        _splash.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { _splash.Close(); }));
        _splash.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        _splash = null;
    }

    public static void Update(int value, string description)
    {
        Update((double)value, description);
    }

    public static void Update(double value, string description)
    {
        if (_splash == null)
            return;

        _splash.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            //It takes 120 ms to progress 10%.
            var da = new DoubleAnimation(value, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Math.Abs(_splash.ProgressBar.Value - value) * 12)))
            {
                EasingFunction = new PowerEase { Power = 3 }
            };

            _splash.ProgressBar.BeginAnimation(RangeBase.ValueProperty, da);
            _splash.textBlock.Text = description;
        });
    }


}
```

Splash.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Splash : Window
{
    public Splash()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DragMove();
    }
}
```

Splash xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SplashScreenWPF.Splash"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SplashScreenWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Splash" Height="300" Width="300" MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="147*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="145*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="135*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="134*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button  Margin="30" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Button  Margin="30" Grid.Column="2" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,66,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="16" Margin="24,66,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Indeed this works, I starting to believe that it has something to do with the fact that I'm calling from another assembly, even if there's nothing being shared. Yet, it does not make sense.

Comment: My code also creates the SplashScreen inside the new `Thread`. This bug is so strange, if I hover and remove the cursor fast enough, it does not crash.

Comment: If thats the case, i wonder if it is to do with your tool tips

Comment: Try looking at my solution: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvXoqrDa9QWWbA-Cgt4qMAn9OkI

Comment: `If thats the case, i wonder if it is to do with your tool tips` OMG, that's IT!

Comment: I removed the tooltips from the buttons and started working! You can add this as the answer. Later I'll try to understand why it was crashing, maybe the `ToolTipService.Placement`

Comment: I have the tool tips running in my solution, did you have a chance to download it and check it out? If you call the update function does the progress bar fill?

Answer (score 0):

The hover is happening in the GUI thread, the button logic you have is in a different thread; resolve that and you will resolve the problem.

Have the `DragMove` operation invoked back to the GUI thread. Something like this:

```
public static void SafeOperationToGuiThread(Action operation)
{
   System.Windows.Application.Current?.Dispatcher?.Invoke(operation);
}
```

Called such as

```
 SafeOperationToGuiThread( DragMove );
```

---

If you are not using C# 6 (in VS 2015) then put sanity null checks at each of the `?` shown.

Comment: I don't think this is an issue, he don't even click button, so no dragging occurs yet.